# What's the translation of "standing bars" in French?

Tags: traduction

A standing bar is a bar where patrons drink while standing up.

[Example](http://blog.sundaysgrocery.com/2017/07/tachinomi-japans-standing-bars):

> Tachinomi, also known as standing bars, are staples in Japan.

What's the translation of "standing bars" in French? Google Translate and DeepL didn't help.

Comment: I am not sure there is a specific french word, in any of bistrot, bar, buvette, troquet  you might find seating place or not. **buvette** might be the closest.

Comment: Could you provide some other examples ? is this a japanese thing or not ?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say that there is an established French term for this, but tachinomi is sometimes referred to simply as a *bar debout*, as in the following quotation (from [this travel site](https://www.clicatour.com/fr/excursion/japon/tokyo/visite-gastronomique-retro-de-shibuya)):

> Les Tachinomi sont des bars debout japonais. Traditionnellement, il
> s'agissait d'un type de bar simple situé autour des gares ou dans des
> quartiers populaires, où les salariés venaient se détendre après une
> dure journée de travail.

Unless the context is clear, you might wish to follow this example and say *bar debout **japonais***, because it is possible to refer to, for example, a French bar also as a *bar debout*, see [“Certains bars à Toulouse préfèrent fermer totalement dès lundi“](https://www.lejournaltoulousain.fr/les-breves-du-jt/certains-bars-a-toulouse-preferent-fermer-totalement-des-lundi-92242/):

> Ce bar à vin défend l’esprit de bistrot. Un lieu de partage et
> d’échange, un lieu ou les gens discutent accoudés sur un comptoir.
> Autrement dit, c’est un bar debout. Ce qui ne sera plus possible en
> raison de la crise sanitaire.

Here we see that the bar in question is considered a place were people meet to drink and to socialize, as in a bistro. This is precisely how the Japanese see the tachinomi: as a (simpler) version of the izakaya, the Japanese bistro or pub.